# Loop Array of Object and connect them together by different keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, object

I'm trying to loop thru products array and find its description in description array. The product `id` and description `parent` represent the same product. If the description could be found, push the product with its description to the results array.

I don't really know how this loop should look like.

Products

```
let products = [
  {
    "id": "43",
    "titel": "Phone",
    "price": "211"
  },{
    "id": "76",
    "titel": "Battery",
    "price": "34"
  },{
    "id": "102",
    "titel": "Pen",
    "price": "45"
  },{
    "id": "127",
    "titel": "Apple",
    "price": "10"
  }
]
```

Descriptions

```
let descriptions= [
  {
    "description": "Good battery",
    "parent": "76"
  },{
    "description": "Sharp pen",
    "parent": "102"
  },
]
```

Expected output `results`

```
let results = [
  {
    "id": "76",
    "titel": "Battery",
    "price": "34"
    "description": "Good battery",
    "parent": "76"
  },{
    "id": "102",
    "titel": "Pen",
    "price": "45"
    "description": "Sharp pen",
    "parent": "102"
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) which allows to transform an array to another type of Object of array.

combine with the [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to check if item with a given `id` exists in the `descriptions` Array

```js
let products = [
  {
    "id": "43",
    "titel": "Phone",
    "price": "211"
  },{
    "id": "76",
    "titel": "Battery",
    "price": "34"
  },{
    "id": "102",
    "titel": "Pen",
    "price": "45"
  },{
    "id": "127",
    "titel": "Apple",
    "price": "10"
  }
]


let descriptions= [
  {
    "description": "Good battery",
    "parent": "76"
  },{
    "description": "Sharp pen",
    "parent": "102"
  },
]

const result = products.reduce((acc, item) => {

  // Check if the description of the current product exists
  let exist = descriptions.find(desc => {
    return item.id === desc.parent;
  });
  
  if(exist) {
    return acc.concat({...item, description: exist.description});
  }
  return acc;
}, []);


console.log(result);
```

If you add another array `comments` you can update the code instead of to concatenate the item in the `accumulator` directly you'll create another object which after finding the related comment in the comment array you'll add the comment key in that object with their comment.

Here is the code

```js
let products = [
  {
    "id": "43",
    "titel": "Phone",
    "price": "211"
  },{
    "id": "76",
    "titel": "Battery",
    "price": "34"
  },{
    "id": "102",
    "titel": "Pen",
    "price": "45"
  },{
    "id": "127",
    "titel": "Apple",
    "price": "10"
  }
]


let descriptions= [
  {
    "description": "Good battery",
    "parent": "76"
  },{
    "description": "Sharp pen",
    "parent": "102"
  },
]

let comments = [
  {
    "comment": "Good battery comment",
    "product": "76",
  }, {
    "comment": "Sharp pen comment",
    "product": "102"
  }
];

const result = products.reduce((acc, item) => {

  // Check if the description of the current product exists
  let productExists = descriptions.find(desc => {
    return item.id === desc.parent;
  });
  
  let commentExists = comments.find(comment => {
    return item.id === comment.product
  });
  let newItem = null;
  
  if(productExists) {
    newItem = {
      ...item, 
      description: productExists.description
     };
  }
  if(commentExists) {
    newItem.comment = commentExists.comment;
  }
  
  return newItem? acc.concat(newItem): acc;
}, []);


console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply everything works just fine. I wonder how I can add another array. For example `comments` where the `product` key in the comment array equals `id` in the products array?

Comment: I have updated the code to consider array of comments

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the descriptions, then use there [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and merge them together into a new object, with [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and push them to your results

```js
let products = [
    {
      "id": "43",
      "titel": "Phone",
      "price": "211"
    },{
      "id": "76",
      "titel": "Battery",
      "price": "34"
    },{
      "id": "102",
      "titel": "Pen",
      "price": "45"
    },{
      "id": "127",
      "titel": "Apple",
      "price": "10"
    }
  ];
  let descriptions= [
    {
      "description": "Good battery",
      "parent": "76"
    },{
      "description": "Sharp pen",
      "parent": "102"
    },
  ];
  let results = [];
  for (const desc of descriptions) {
      const product = products.find(v => v.id === desc.parent);
      if (!product) {
          continue;
      }
      results.push(Object.assign({}, product, desc));
  }
  console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = descriptions.map(descr => {
    const product = products.find(prod => prod.id === descr.parent);
    return {...product, ...descr}
})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.